# Why is Automapper causing a loading delay in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, automapper, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Currently I'm using automapper with dependency injection to easily map my Data Transfer Objects to View Models and vice versa. I've configured the maps using profiles, for example:

```
public class CategoryProfile : Profile
{
    public CategoryProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CategoryDTO, CategoryViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Questions, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.SubCategories, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

And in my Program.cs (in the .client project), I've added them:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CategoryProfile)));
```

This works and I can easily access the mapper profiles using dependency injection. I have quite a few profiles and using this single line they're all added perfectly. The problem is that this causes quite a long load time. From what I've managed to find out this is cause automapper has to look through the entire assembly (I don't know how fast it can do this) and then create the maps for all the profiles. Once this is done, everything else works instantly but the first time is just taking too long and I would like to optimize this.

I can force automapper to load all the maps by adding this in Program.cs, which works better as the entire app doesn't just freeze in between but rather the first time it's loading:

```
WebAssemblyHost host = builder.Build();
host.Services.GetService<IMapper>();
await host.RunAsync();
```

But this is far from perfect, as it's just moving to problem somewhere else.

My question is what causes this increased loadtime? Is it having to go through assembly and checking for profiles or is the creation of all these mappers simply and intense task. And if it is, is there any way to improve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this delay is only when the application pool loads. Once it has loaded, it will be fine. When you deploy your app, access some page once to force this to load. That way when everyone else accesses it, it will not affect them. Lastly, are you sure it is automapper causing it and what makes you think so?

Comment: You would have to profile it to find out. The MyGet build is faster. But WebAssembly is not exactly .Net. So the performance there is kind of unpredictable.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Previously I injected IMapper only when I actually needed it. This would mean that the first time I loaded a page that used IMapper there would be a load delay of ~4sec (depending on the device). During this load delay the entire UI froze, so I moved it to the program.cs class to make it look like it's part of the initial application loadtime. If I don't call automapper the loadtime isn't there. And as it's webassembly this happens every time someone opens (and thus loads) the app. In serverside this isn't an issue as it's already loaded by someone at some point.

Comment: Ok fair enough, yes my comment was for server side.

Comment: _"everything else works instantly but the first time is just taking too long and I would like to optimize this."_ - do you want to optimize the first time AutoMapper loads, or shift the moment it does it? If the first option, try to add AutoMapper using concrete profile types instead of whole assembly, if you have so many of them, or your assembly is quite large. If the second option, check out [configuration compilation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#configuration-compilation) in the docs.